# Logging file from karma (jasmine test) using gulp

Tags: logging, jasmine, gulp, karma-runner

I have a troubles writing the output of my tests to an external file using Karma and gulp. I do get the complete output in my console.
In my text file i get the basic output but not my actual results of my tests.
(basic = Requesting/fetching source files, web-server warnings like 404)

Basically i want my passed, skipped and failed tests written in an external file. (which i don't have right now)

This is my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['spec'],
    specReporter: {
        maxLogLines: 10,         // limit number of lines logged per test
        suppressErrorSummary: false,  // do not print error summary
        suppressFailed: false,  // do not print information about failed tests
        suppressPassed: false,  // do not print information about passed tests
        suppressSkipped: false,  // do not print information about skipped tests
        showSpecTiming: false // print the time elapsed for each spec
      },
    browsers: ['IE'],//, 'Chrome', 'Firefox', 'PhantomJS'
    plugins: [
      'karma-*',
      'karma-spec-reporter'
    ],
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    port:9876,
    autoWatch: true,
    files: [ "**/*.js"
    ],
    loggers:[{
            type: 'console'
        },
        {
            type: 'file',
            absolute: false,
            filename: 'logfile.log',
            maxLogSize: 20480,
            backups: 10,
        }
    ],
    colors:true
  });
};
```

gulp:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
  new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: false,

    }, done).start();
});
```

This works fine: karma start > log.log
in console

Answer (score 0):

Ended up listening to `process.stdout.write` in Node.
Wrote a function to "decorate" `write` and store the output into an array. I needed it to filter out particular logs from Jasmine, but you could do it then write to a file.

```
function watchFunc(obj,func){
    if(!func || typeof func !== 'string'){
        return;
    }
    (function(o,f,ofunc){
        o[f] = function(){
            o[f].calls.args = o[f].args.concat(arguments);
            o[f].calls.length++;
            o[f].calls.returns = o[f].calls.returns.concat(ofunc.apply(obj,arguments));
            return o[f].calls.returns[o[f].calls.length - 1];
        };
        o[f].calls = {
            length: 0,
            args: [],
            returns: [],
            originalFunction: ofunc,
            unwatch: function(){
                var ret = o[f].calls;
                delete ret.unwatch;
                delete ret.originalFunction;
                o[f] = ofunc;
                return ret;
            }
        };
    })(obj,func,obj[func]);
}

/* In Node environment */
watchFunc(process.stdout,'write');

// process.stdout.write.calls === {length: 0, args: [], returns: [], ...}

/* Run your Jasmine tasks */
// ...
// Then can retrieve the logs.
var logs = process.stdout.write.calls.unwatch();

logs.args.forEach(a => {...}); // Note this is an array of Arguments objects
```

Change it to do whatever you need, but it worked for me to get the Jasmine logs.
I also wrote a task to start the `watchFunc` before Jasmine, and another to `unwatch` after so that I wouldn't get anything else written to `process.stdout`.

Hope it helps! :)